# How to download Noto Color Emoji into PNG

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, emoji

I would like to pick any of the emoji in the following site, select the resolution and download it into PNG image whith transparent background. However I could not find any way to do this systematiccaly since I would need to do for a few emojis.

can you recommend how this can be achieved?

https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji/glyphs

I tried using some libraries like PIL where I provide the emoji directly. But this doesn't really work well and if I achieve to download the picture, the emoji it is shown in bad way (the layout and shape is not so nice as the once I can see on the page above). So I would like to be able to download exactly with the cool style I can see on website above

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pillow (version 10) mostly works for me; it needs a bit of hand-holding but gets there in the end.  Note that I've got these fonts installed system-wide, you might need to download them and update the path appropriately.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# see https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3346 for "size=109"
noto = ImageFont.truetype(
    '/usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf',
    size=109,
)

text = ""
bbox = noto.getbbox(text)

im = Image.new('RGBA', bbox[2:])
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.text((0,0), text, font=noto, embedded_color=True)
im.save('emoji.png')
```

Which results in the following PNG being saved:

[image: PIL Output]

Answer (score 0):

You can download them from their Github repository: https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/png

For example ‍⚖️ with 128px is at
`https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/blob/main/png/128/emoji_u1f468_200d_2696.png` where `u1f468_200d_2696` is the unicode code points of the emoji as hexadecimal numbers.

You can get that in Python like this:

```py
emoji = "‍⚖️"
unicode_points = ["{:x}".format(ord(x)) for x in emoji]
print(unicode_points) # ['1f468', '200d', '2696', 'fe0f']
```

You would have to modify the `unicode_points` list to convert it to the format of the url e.g. remove the `'fe0f'` and join it together with `_`